# how to apply XGBoost feature_importances_ on few features

Tags: python, xgboost, feature-engineering

I have used a standard version of Algorithm A which has features x, y, and z
then I had used feature engineering to add for algorithm A new features (10 new features)

I would like to use the feature importance method to select the most important features between only the 10 features without removing any of the (x, y, z features)
can I identify first the list of features on which I would like to apply the feature importance method?

I have tried this source code but it plots all features:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from xgboost import plot_importance

# fit model to training data
xgb_model = XGBClassifier(random_state = 0 )
xgb_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Feature Importances : ", xgb_model.feature_importances_)

# plot feature importance
plot_importance(xgb_model)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I was wondering if you tried dropping the three features from X_train and then performing xgb_model.fit(X_train,y_train)?

Comment: no, I keep the three features and I have trained all the 13 features; but I would like to compare just the importance of the10 new created features in order to reduce some features that have not a big influence so that the last version of the model will include (x, y, z, + certain of the most important features)